# How to find and print the least frequent value of lottery statistics?

Tags: python

I have this code and everything works as I need. However, the printing of the least frequent numbers is incorrect. I believe the `# sort` and `bottom_10` are the errors of the code.

Here is the link to the: [`powerball.csv`](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/lottery-powerball-winning-numbers-beginning-2010) data file.

Code:

```
# file that needs to be read
filename = 'powerball.csv'

# empty dictionary will contain number and its frequency, number is the lottery number
# which will act as the key while the value will be the number of times the lottery
# number appeared in the file
number_dict = {}

# open the file in read mode
with open(filename, 'r') as infile:
    # read one line at a time
    for line in infile.readlines():
        # split the line by space
        line = line.strip().split()
       # pick the last 6 numbers which will be the lottery numbers
        numbers = line[-6:]
        # iterate over each number
        for number in numbers:
            # check if the number exist is in the dicitonary
            if number_dict.get(number) is None:
                # if its a new number add to the dictionary with count as 1
                number_dict[number] = 1
            else:
                # if the number already exist, increment the value by 1
                number_dict[number] += 1

    # sort the dictionary in reverse order that is number with highest frequency will apppear first
    number_list=sorted(number_dict.items(),key=lambda pair:pair[1],reverse=True)
    # sort the dictionary in reverse that is number with least frequency will apppear first
    number_list=sorted(number_dict.items(),key=lambda pair:pair[1],reverse=True)

    # slice the top 10 records
    top_10=number_list[:10]
    # slice the bottom 10 records
    bottom_10=number_list[:-10-1:-1]

    # print the numbers and its frequency
    print('The 10 most frequent numbers are:')
    for data in top_10:
        print('{} was drawn {} times'.format(data[0],data[1]))

    print('The 10 least frequently drawn numbers:')
    for data in bottom_10:
        print('{} was drawn {} times'.format(data[0],data[1]))
```

Comment: Are you aware that the lines where you assign `number_list` are the same? You're doing the same sort twice.

Comment: oh true. How would i alter it so that it finds the least frequent numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Slicing seems odd here. What about convert the dict/list to a dataframe and using a head and tail function? i.e.

```
top10 = data.head(10)
bottom10 = data.tail(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your parsing of rows to numbers is wrong, if you'll print `numbers` you will see it parsed it as:

```
['10/14/2020,21', '37', '52', '53', '58', '05,2']
```

A more accurate parser will be:

```
line = line.strip().split(',')
numbers = line[1].split() + [line[2]]
```

Or even better - use [CSV](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) reader.

Comment: my original output  was :
The 10 most frequent numbers are:
41 was drawn 100 times
32 was drawn 99 times
...
The 10 least frequently drawn numbers:
10/24/2020,18 was drawn 1 times
10/21/2020,01 was drawn 1 times
...                                                      But I need to remove the data. How would I do this?